# When does asp.net HTML encode elements?

Tags: asp.net

In my database, I have a text field that contains escaped data:

```
"O&#39;Neal"
```

I am trying to output it to my page like this:

```
LastName.InnerText = DB.LastName;
```

However, this results in this HTML on my page:

```
<h2 id="LastName">O&amp;#39;Neal</h2>
```

What makes asp.net encode my HTML like this, and can I trust it to do this all the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `InnerHtml` instead of `InnerText` which will not encode data.

Answer (score 2):

The [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innertext.aspx) of `InnerText` clearly says in the remarks section:

> Unlike the InnerHtml property, the InnerText property automatically encodes special characters to and from HTML entities. HTML entities allow you to display special characters, such as the < character, that a browser would ordinarily interpret as having special meaning. The < character would be interpreted as the start of a tag and is not displayed on the page. To display the < character, you would need to use the entity `&lt;`.
>
> For example, if the InnerText property is set to "`<b> Hello </b>`", the `<` and `>` symbols are converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively. The rendered output would be: `&lt;`b`&gt`; Hello `&lt;`/b`&gt;`. The `&lt;` and `&gt;` entities would indicate to the browser that these characters are to be displayed on the page. The browser will not detect the `<b>` tags and display the text in a bold font. The text displayed on the page is: `<b>`Hello`</b>`.
>
> To prevent automatic HTML encoding and decoding, use the InnerHtml property.